# How to register the id div in the Vue button?

Tags: vue.js, button

there is such a construction:

```
<div v-show="visible" id="ten"></div>
<div v-show="visible" id="twelve"></div>
<button v-if="!isHidden" v-on:click="visible=!visible, 
isHidden = true">Click Me!</button>

<script>
export default {
 data() {
  return {
    visible: false,
    isHidden: false,
          }
/*.....................................*/
```

can I specify in this line that only the "ten" div should be displayed?

```
v-on:click="visible=!visible, isHidden = true"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need a separate variable if you want to control the visibility of child elements separately. For instance:

```js
data() {
  return {
    ten_isVisible: true,
    twelve_isVisible: true
  }
}
```

```html
<div v-show="ten_isVisible" id="ten"></div>
<div v-show="twelve_isVisible" id="twelve"></div>
```

And of course, you would need separate controls (buttons, checkboxes, whatever you like) to toggle the visibility of the different elements.